# I want to know the number of fingers such as two-finger simultaneous touch

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift on iOS and want to get the number of fingers detected by a Gesture Recognizer, then process the numerical value of movement. How do you get the number of fingers, in order to do something like a two-finger simultaneous touch?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if(touches.first == nil) { return }
    let loc = touches.first!.location(in: view)
    let resolution = view.frame.size
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if(touches.first == nil) { return }
    let loc = touches.first!.location(in: view)
    let resolution = view.frame.size
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you want to know the number of fingers

Just do `touches.count`, but make sure to set [`view.isMultipleTouchEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622519-ismultipletouchenabled) to true. However, consider using [pan gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_pan_gestures) instead. They're easy to use and will save you a lot of code.

---

Edit: If you're using `UIGestureRecognizer`, you shouldn't be using `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`. Instead, connect your gesture recognizer to an `@IBAction`.

```
@IBAction func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
   print("Number of touches: \(sender.numberOfTouches)")
}
```

Comment: Does it mean that it cannot be taken like minimumNumberOfTouches and maximumNumberOfTouches under normal circumstances?

Comment: @x001017 what cannot be taken? Under normal circumstances?

Comment: Is it possible to count the number of fingers in `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in a normal situation where touches Moved is used as in the question?

Comment: @x001017 see my edit. You shouldn't be using both `UIGestureRecognizer` and `touchesBegan`/`touchesMoved` at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. You can't use it normally.
That's too bad. Thank you for using them at the same time.

Comment: @x001017 note that you *can* get the position, translation, etc from `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, just like `touchesMoved`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer